# A question regarding hydrogen emission and absorption spectrum

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, atomic-structure

I have read in many articles as well as my textbook that when an electric discharge is passed through a sample of hydrogen gas it excites the electrons and glows emitting light.When this light is refracted through a prism we can see different wavelengths of visible light which is obtained from dexcitation of electrons from different energy levels like from n=4,n=5 etc.My question is that when an electric discharge is passed or the sample is heated shouldn't the electrons in all the hydrogen atoms excite to the same level and not to different levels and thus emit same wavelength of light?For example when a sample of hydrogen gas is put through an electric discharge since all atoms receive same energy shouldn't the electrons in all atoms excite to same energy level and dexcite from the same energy level like from n=2 to n=3 and back and not to different energy levels like one electron in one atom excites from n=2 to n=3 and the one electron in another atom excite from n=2 to n=4 shouldn't both excite to n=3?I hope you get an idea of what I am trying to say.

Comment: The atoms are excited by collisions with high energy electrons and do **not** all receive the same energy! Some get excited from n=1 to n=2, some from n=1 to n=4, etc. Then they de-excite by various pathways, i.e., in a single step or a cascade of steps. So you get the Balmer series, Lyman series, etc. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series.

Comment: So you mean to say  based on the collision elastic or inelastic the electron in different atoms gets excited to different levels?

Comment: Ok so when I heat the sample of gas to high temperature it glows but in this case why do electrons in different atoms excite to different levels though they receive same energy?

Comment: Even when  the source of excitation is heating, the available energy for thermally induced excitation is spread over wide range. Remember [Maxwell-Boltzmann statistical speed distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell–Boltzmann_distribution) for ideal gas molecules. At the given T, molecules have wide range of energies and therefore collision energies.

Comment: They do not receive the same energy! A hot gas or plasma has a distribution of energies of particles. Some are fast and highly energetic, others are slow and have low energies. Collisions are frequent and any given particle may be slow one instant and fast the next. And vice versa. Average energies are just that: averages. You need to drop the idea of “same energy”. Just saw what @Poutnik said. Same.

Comment: In an electric discharge, electrons may get any energy higher than $50$ electron-volt, depending on the type of device. With such energies, they hit hydrogen atoms. To send the 1s electron of hydrogen from the lowest level to the first excited level, $\pu{10.205 eV}$ is required. To send it to the second excited level, $\pu{12.084 eV}$ is needed. To extract the electron totally out of the atom, $\pu{13.606 eV}$ is required. All these transitions are possible in a collision electron-hydrogen, as the "missile" has enough energy to initiate all of them